# Triggering a Method of a page from another page C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, triggers, html

Guys I have a calendar on a popup window. I need the date selected on it into a textbox of the page from which the popup was opened(that is in the popup's parent page).

I have set public access methods that is getting the date chosen on the popup as first registering a directive as

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/DateFrom.aspx" %>
```

then in popup

```
//making value of hidden field available to the "destination page"
        public string from
        {
            get
            {
                return hdnFrom.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I can also access this value on the parent page by a method as

```
public string display()
{
    Label1.Text = PreviousPage.from;
}
```

however I need the date to be displayed as soon as it is selected in the popup.

How can I trigger the `display()` from the popup window ?

Comment: have you tried `PreviousPage.FindControl`??

Comment: here is msdn link for help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx

Comment: you may use `SelectionChanged` event in popup to trigger `display()`

Comment: @Saghir A. Khatri ,I cannot do this as the method is in a different page. How do i register it to the popup so as to trigger it from the opoup

Comment: Save selected date in session variable and use that session variable in page where u want to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which is sort of like a reverse approach when compared to [Saghir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559082/triggering-a-method-of-a-page-from-another-page-c-sharp/19559823#19559823)'s approach.

You have your parent page open the popup page like this:

```
function openCalendar(){
    window.open('calendar.aspx', '_blank', 'width=200,height=100');
}

function populateCalendarTextbox(val){
    document.getElementById('calendarbox').value = val;
}
```

In your popup page (calendar.aspx) you write some code like this:

```
function sendToParent(value){
    //Assume value is assigned from the calendar control 
    //by passing as argument to this function
    window.opener.populateCalendarTextbox(value);
    window.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to send value from child popup to parent webpage
here is the script for your `child.aspx`

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function childFunc()

{

    return document.getElementById ("<%Calender1.ClientID%>").value;

}

</script>
```

and in your `parent.aspx`

```
<script type = "text/javascript">


var PopUpObj;

function popUp(url)
```

{
        PopUpObj = window.open(url);
        PopUpObj.focus();
    }

```
function callChildFunc()
{
    if(popUpObj != null && !popUpObj.closed) 
    {
        var val = popUpObj.childFunc();
        alert(val);
    }
}
</script>
```

hope this will help